# PHP Array stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, stdclass

I have this array

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 252062474) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 252062474) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 252062474) 
)
```

I need echo all of id's

I tried,

```
foreach($result as $item) { 
   echo $item->id;
}
```

but no luck

I try `json_decode()`

again no luck I use php 5.5.8

I know this work

```
echo $item[0]->id;
```

but i don't how many index is there

any idea?

Comment: try json_decode($array,true), it will give u an array and u can loop through the array to get data.

Comment: I tried but no luck
recently I changed my php version to php 5.5.8 I think all problems goes there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confused on `foreach()`. If this works:

```
echo $item[0]->id;
```

Then you would need:

```
foreach($item as $result) {
    echo $result->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

***Code***

```
foreach($result as $p) {
    echo $p['id'] . "<br/>";
}
```

***Output***

```
252062474
252062474
252062474
```

Comment: returns: 00
var_dump($p['id']) returns: NULL NULL string(1) "0" NULL string(1) "0"

Answer (score 0):

This array could be looped through and data could be retrieved. As you are saying its not working I have added the following code to illustrate how it works right from generating the array for you.

```
// generating an array like you gave in the example. Note that ur array has same value
// for all the ids in but my example its having different values
$arr = array();

$init = new stdClass;
$init->id = 252062474 ;
$arr[] = $init;
$init = new stdClass;
$init->id = 252062475 ;
$arr[] = $init;
$init = new stdClass;
$init->id = 252062476 ;
$arr[] = $init;
print_r($arr);
```

The above array is same as yours

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 252062474 )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 252062475 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 252062476 )
      )
```

Now the following code will loop through and get the data as

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    echo $key.'  ID is :: '.$val->id;
    echo '<br />';
}
```

The output will be

```
0 ID is :: 252062474
1 ID is :: 252062475
2 ID is :: 252062476
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($result as $item) { 
   $item = (array)$item;
   echo $item['id'];
}
```